# Running Apache Storm in local mode connection errors

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, apache-storm, executorservice

EDIT: So this got "solved" when I increase the sleep time but still get connection/timeout errors

```
59297 [Thread-14] ERROR o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Failed to Sync Supervisor
```

here is my custom topology:

```
public class MyTopology {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("NameSpout", new NameSpout());
        builder.setBolt("NameBolt", new MyBolt()).shuffleGrouping("NameSpout");

        Config config = new Config();
        config.setDebug(true);
        config.setNumWorkers(1);

        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();

        try {

            cluster.submitTopology("TryingOne", config, builder.createTopology());
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            cluster.shutdown();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, LocalCluster will take care of it. You shouldn't run your own Zookeeper server when using LocalCluster.

In order to rule out issues with the environment you're running in, please try checking out and running this topology https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.2/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/starter/ExclamationTopology.java.

If it works, it will be an issue with your project configuration. If not, there's likely an issue with the environment you're in.

Comment: I am still getting connection errors (slightly different types). This is really confusing because I thought localmode had nothing to do with the surrounding environment.

Comment: It shouldn't. LocalCluster starts up an embedded Zookeeper instance. Just to be clear, are you seeing only connection errors and no topology output (in your code sample, you should increase the sleep time, 1 second is likely not enough)? Maybe your OS is blocking the ports Zookeeper wants to use for some reason?

Comment: Yes only seeing errors and no topology result. I'm using macOS. I have a feeling it's something to do with Zookeeper ports. Since it's internal, I don't think a firewall or vpn would change anything?

Comment: I don't know. As far as I know Zookeeper should work on MacOS. Could you try running the ExclamationTopology, and pastebin the full console output, as well as the command you're running?

Comment: Okay so what I did was extend the sleep time even more and I do see my stuff emitted now. However, the error I get is still there as it doesn't shut down properly. I'm gonna accept your answer but wish I knew why this error is being caused.

Comment: Please don't edit your question into a different question. The answer given now doesn't really match the question you are asking. This will be confusing for other readers. If you want to ask another question, just post a new one.